# When it's text a longer then cross the border

Tags: javascript, css

[picture of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6lzC.png)

Can I do something to wrap my text inside or to adjust a width of tasks.
It would be good if I can change a height of tasks or something like that.
I think about to contain a certain number of words, but that would be destroy UX.

Please help me to solve this problem it's a really headache.

Here is a css code:

```
  /*My code*/
html{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.wrapp1{
    width:350px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:auto;

    margin-top: 80px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 22px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 22px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 22px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
}

.header{
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
.header h1{
    font-size:24px;
    color:#111;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    width:260px;
    height:auto;
    font-size:16px;
     margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height:40px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 22px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 22px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 22px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
}
ul li{
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.icons{
    float:right;
   margin-top:-37px;
}

.delete{
    margin-right:-10px;
}

button{
    border:none;
    background:none;
}
button img{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.insert{
    margin-top:30px;
    border-top:1px solid #dddddd;

}
.insert input{
    width:220px;
    height:30px;
    border:none;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.insert button{
    float:right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Luka, consider using overflow and text-overflow css attributes. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/

Comment: @lukaSale, you should also provide your HTML, so we can help you fix your code. Even better would be a Codepen or Jsfiddle.

Comment: @PaulThomas I do the trick with the word-wrap, but thank you.

Comment: @antoni It's already solved, but thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the word-wrap attribute in CSS to edit elements' word-wrapping behaviors.

Here's a reference code from W3 school:
https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

hope it was helpful, thanks.